# Ido completion does not find all options

Tags: emacs, ido

I'm trying to use ido mode in Emacs 24.5.1 to find files recursively in subdirs. This is my config:

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-case-fold t)
(setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)
```

When I C-x C-f to invoke `ido-find-file` and type in "paym", I get the following 4 matches: `Payment/ | PaymentsInteractorTests.swift | PaymentsRepository.swift | StoreKitPaymentRepositoryTests.swift`

However there's also a file called `PaymentsInteractor.swift` in the project, which ido does not find.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way how to make ido search better?

Comment: Do you ever see more than 4 matches? Perhaps you can solve this with `(setq ido-max-prospects 10)`.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I increased the number, which was another drawback I was experiencing. However it did not solve the original issue.

Comment: Is `PaymentsInterator.swift` in the current directory? ido will not recursively search directories for you, so if that file is in `Payment/` for example, it will not show up (until you select `Payment/`).

Comment: Indeed, `PaymentsInteractor.swift` is inside the `Payment/` dir. Do you know if there's a way how to make ido descend into directories? I was under the impression it's the default behaviour.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do that with `ido`. If you want that feature,  you'll want to look into `helm` (and its function, `helm-find-file`).